# How to implement different type of users in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The question is specific on how to implement the below scenario.

In my application I have 3 different types of users `Customer`, `Student` and `Admin`. It's a subscription based app so a `Customer` can have a `Plan`, `Student` may have other things and so on.

How can I implement the above users with Spring Security? Is it a good idea to extend `Customer`, `Student`, and `Admin` from Spring's User class?

I'm new to Spring so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is "user roles" in spring security. This is very basic work with spring security. Did you try to search any tutorial for spring security?

Yes, you can implement this. Yes, it is good idea to extend Customer, Student, and Admin from Spring's User class.